# Juntar vários commits de uma branch

Tags: git, github

Tenho a seguinte situação: Criei uma branch, para a qual fiz diversos commits, fiz o push para o github, agora pretendia juntar esses commits, que já estão no github em um só, para não ficarem commits de "lixo". Alguém sabe como se processa?

Comment: Você quer no caso fazer uma PR (Pull request) para master?

Comment: Você precisará fazer um 'rebase' optando por fazer 'squash' nos commits que não deseja mais (eles não serão apagados mas unificados com seu anterior).

Comment: Aliás você não apagará os 'commits' de verdade, apenas os abandonará e criará outros bastante parecidos com os anteriores.

Comment: Sim, já experimentei fazer isso mas não consegui muito bem tive de usar o comando `git rebase -i -root` e quando foi para fazer o push tive que forçar, isto não é recomendado pois não?

Answer (score 1):

Se os commits que deseja unir desta branch remota seja os **últimos** commits dela, você precisa fazer o `squash` dos commits na branch local e depois fazer um force push para a branch remota.

Veja um exemplo com a branch `master`. Primeiro, vamos pegar os últimos 2 commits e fazer o *squash* deles:

```
git rebase -i origin/master~2 master
```

Agora faço o force push para a branch remota:

```
git push --force origin master
```

Um aviso: só faça isto se **ninguém abriu uma branch** a partir de um destes commits que deseja unir.

Comment: com essas linhas de comando eu perdi 7 dos meus arquivos... Não executem esses comando, a não ser que tenham segurança do que estão fazendo!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer o seguinte:

[1] `git checkout -b nomedanovabranch`

[2]  `git checkout nomedasuabranch`

[1] Dessa forma você irá criar uma nova branch e já irá mudar para ela

[2] Dessa forma você irá mudar para uma branch já existente

Para juntar os commits será preciso fazer um 'merge' das branchs, é só você fazer o seguinte:

```
git pull origin NomedaBranchQueVoceQuerPegarosCommits
```

Pronto, dessa forma (dando pull), o git irá fazer o merge automático para você e irá pegar os commits da branch que você acabou de dar pull.

Depois é só você subir para o seu repositório

```
git add . ou git add -A (Vai adicionar todos os arquivos)

git commit -m "Fazendo um merge"

git push
```

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Comment: Nesta situação, ao apagar a branch antiga, há algum problema?

Comment: Depois de fazer o merge  e subir para a nova branch você pode apagar sim.